# flutter: list.sort() or comparator fucntion is not work

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

in my project,
I use the Firestore and use AysncSnapshot
I want to sort that firestore documents but, only first connection to DB(Firestore)
so i don`t want to use orderBy() method of Firestore

but, my sort function don`t work
help me and sorry my english

```
  sortBucketList(){
    bucketListSnapshot.data.documents..sort((a, b){
      switch(_sorting){
        case Sort.importance:
          return (b['_importance'] < (a['_importance']))?-1:1;
        case Sort.creationDate:
          return (b['_startDate'].toDate().isAfter(a['_startDate'].toDate())?-1:1);
        case Sort.title:
          if(b['_state'] == 0 && a['_state'] == 0) printLog("${b['_title']} & ${a['_title']}" + b['_title'].toString().compareTo(a['_title'].toString()).toString());
          return (b['_title'].toString().compareTo(a['_title'].toString()));
        default:
          return (b['_title'].toString().compareTo(a['_title'].toString()));
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: `List.sort` docs are saying: "The compare function must act as a [Comparator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Comparator.html)." - your compare function for two first cases do not return `0` - it only returns `-1` and `1`

Comment: @pskink but, when i use the compareTo function for two first cases...
don`t work also...

Comment: input data is bucketListSnapshot is AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>, _sorting is enum value how the list sort and data after calling sort() method is sorted bucketLsitSnapshot.data.documents by order for enum value...
do you understand this..? i`m sorry for my explanation

Comment: ok input data is _achievementDate : 2021년 3월 20일 오후 5시 33분 42초 UTC+9
_address : ""
_category : ""
_closingDate : null
_content : "asd"
_id : 1616229226052
_image : []
_importance : 3.0
_startDate : 2021년 3월 20일 오후 5시 33분 42초 UTC+9
_state : 1
_title : "completed"
and i want sort by title or importance or statingDate value, compareTo is working well but sort() method return original list

Comment: `sort` method does not return anything: it is `void sort(...)` method, check this: `void main() {
final a = ['horse', 'pig', 'dog', 'cat'];
print(a);
a.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
print(a);
}
`

Comment: yes your code is working well
flutter: [horse, pig, dog, cat]
flutter: [cat, dog, horse, pig]
but, my code is doesn`t work like that

Comment: i have no idea what data you want to sort (like my `[horse, pig, dog, cat]`) so i cannot help more

Comment: i solve the problem, thank u for your help.
the reason of problem is where called sort() method...